# Logstash issue with json_formater [LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries]

Tags: logstash

I have an issue with converting value through logstash, I can't find solution for it. it seems to be linked to the date.

```
#Log line
[2017-08-15 12:30:17] api.INFO: {"sessionId":"a216925---ff5992be7520924ff25992be75209c7","action":"processed","time":1502789417,"type":"bookingProcess","page":"order"} [] []
```

Logstash configuration

```
filter {
        if [type] == "api-prod-log" {
                grok {
                        match => {"message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{WORD:module}.%{WORD:level}: (?<log_message>.*) \[\] \[\]" }
                        add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
                }
                json {
                    source => "log_message"
                    target => "flightSearchRequest"
                    remove_field=>["log_message"]
                }
                date {
                        match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                        timezone => "Asia/Jerusalem"
                }
        }
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of Logstash are you using?
On Logstash 5.2.2 with the following Logstash config:

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" => '\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{WORD:module}.%{WORD:level}: (?<log_message>.*) \[\] \[\]' }
    }
    json {
        source => "log_message"
        target => "flightSearchRequest"
        remove_field=>["log_message"]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        timezone => "Asia/Jerusalem"
    }
}

output{
    stdout {codec => "rubydebug"}
}
```

I get a perfectly correct result and no errors, when I pass your log line as input:

```
{
             "@timestamp" => 2017-08-15T09:30:17.000Z,
    "flightSearchRequest" => {
           "action" => "processed",
        "sessionId" => "a216925---ff5992be7520924ff25992be75209c7",
             "time" => 1502789417,
             "page" => "order",
             "type" => "bookingProcess"
    },
                  "level" => "INFO",
                 "module" => "api",
               "@version" => "1",
                "message" => "[2017-08-15 12:30:17] api.INFO: {\"sessionId\":\"a216925---ff5992be7520924ff25992be75209c7\",\"action\":\"processed\",\"time\":1502789417,\"type\":\"bookingProcess\",\"page\":\"order\"} [] []",
              "timestamp" => "2017-08-15 12:30:17"
}
```

I've removed the check for "type" in the beginning, can you test if that can affect the result?